# Generating Random numbers using ActionScript-3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I am using 16(4x4) grid pattern, in that i need to generate a random number which should not come horizantally continuous three , vertically continuous three,and diagonally continuous three.i am using as3 for coding.

Can Anyone plz help..

Comment: Not very clear, in deed.

Comment: Please edit your question with some clearer information. The horizontal and vertical continious together with the random stuff is confusing at the moment.

Comment: oh sry dude..i will be clear now..

Comment: i will be clear now..my view is while displaying in the 16 grid(4x4),the generated numbers should not  come along the same line horizantally or vertically or diagonally...i have named the 16 grid with 1,2,3 numbers.And i will show some orange blink on the grid where the random number generated.So what i need here is that generated random blink should not come along the same line horizantally or vertically or diagonally..but it can be altered in the same line.thanks

Answer (score 2):

Generating Random Number:

```
var randNum:Number=Math.floor(Math.random()*100)+1;
```

This will generate Random number range 1 to 100 if you want 0 just remove +1 at the end.

You can generate Random numbers by above technique. And in your grid pattern you should handle your condition( which should not come horizantally continuous three)  by some comparison method. if condition fails you have to generate some other number at that point.

**good luck**